# How to remove several elements from the end of std::vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

Let's say I have a `std::vector` of integers:

```
std::vector<int> v;
```

`v` contains 100 elements, and I want to remove the last 10 elements. I can think of this solution:

```
v.erase(v.end() - 10, v.end());
```

Anything better?

Comment: `for (size_t i = 0; i < rm_elements; ++i) v.pop_back();`? This does not seem superior to your solution, though.

Comment: What is "better" to your mind? Your solution is a one-liner and easily understandable.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You may try this:

```
v.resize(v.size()-10);
```

However, you need to benchmark it against your method. I am not sure it is better or even it may be exactly the same.

You may also check the size before resizing:

```
if(v.size()>=10){
    v.resize(v.size()-10);
}
```

**EDIT**:

Resize removes elements at the end of the vectors:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/

> If n is smaller than the current container size, the content is
>   reduced to its first n elements, removing those beyond (and destroying
>   them).

Comment: Are sure `std::vector::resize` always removes the elements at the end? Is that guaranteed by the standard?

Comment: @cad assuming new size is less than original, then yes.

Comment: @cad Edited with reference